# Pass face to describe-face when using function interactively

Tags: faces

How can I pass the face to `describe-face` when using the function interactively?

```
(defun laxy-describe-face (face)
  "TODO"

  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ( (cseq '("mode-line-inactive" "mode-line")) )
      (completing-read "Face: " cseq nil t "mode-line"))))

  (describe-face 'face))
```

Comment: You're code is correct, you should just remove the quote from tha last `'face`

Comment: Would `completing-read` only get me a string and might need a form of `intern` call?

Comment: Why don't you try it? `(describe-face "modeline-inactive")` and `(describe-face 'mode-line-inactive)` both work: `describe-face` does the interning if necessary. You can look at the code and see for yourself: `C-h f describe-face` and then click on the source link at the end of the first sentence in the `*Help*` buffer.

Comment: I only looked at `C-h f describe-face` which says the argument has to be `FACE`.

Comment: Are you referring to `(dolist (f face (buffer-string))   (if (stringp f) (setq f (intern f)))`?

Comment: @Ephram I don't understand your question in your first comment. But did you understand my answer?

Comment: I was trying to pass an actual `face` rather than the string returned by `completing-read`.  Then @NickD commented that `describe-face` also accepts face names as strings.

Comment: `if (stringp f) (setq f (intern f)))`: yup, that's it.