# Calling describe-face at current point

Tags: faces

With the following, how can I call the function interactively so that I can also call `describe-face` at current point?

```
(defun laxy-descface (face)
  "Describe the typeface properties of FACE."

  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ( (cseq '("mode-line-inactive" "mode-line")) )
      (completing-read "Face: " cseq nil t "mode-line"))))

  (describe-face face))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how would be your preferred design, but I would suggest the following:

```lisp
(defun laxy-descface (face)
  "Describe the typeface properties of FACE."

  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ((fap (face-at-point))
           (cseq (append (when fap (list fap)) '("mode-line-inactive" "mode-line")) ))
      (completing-read "Face: " cseq nil t))))

  (describe-face face))
```

Anyway, the essential part is that you can use `(face-at-point)` to get the face at point.

However, if e.g. `hl-line-mode` is active, then you will not get the actual text its face properties. In that case you can use
`(plist-get (text-properties-at (point)) 'face)` instead of `(face-at-point)`.

Comment: I want to display the face properties by selecting from a list.  Either for current point, or else for `mode-line-inactive` or `mode-line`.  Have seen that one can do `(describe-face 'default)` but do not know how appropriate it would be.

Comment: If user wants `face-at-point`, the function should ensure that it always displays face property at point.

Comment: How should the function know if the user wants `face-at-point`? The function would have a different name? Or you would use a universal-argument? Or it determines by the face-at-point (if the text under point has a face property). Please try to think about what you want exactly first, and try to write down your question as clearly as possible, so that we do not have to guess in our answers, and can give the correct answer at once (to the correct question).

Comment: If you would like to use `completing-read` for the `if-then`, then you can change the `append` to an `or`. If you would like to decide by the face available at point, then additionally use an `if` in the body of the function. If you would like to decide by universal argument, then implement as such. If you'll be clear then I can modify the answer to the correct one at once...

Comment: would be part of `cseq` for `completing-read`.  `(cseq '("char-after-point" "mode-line-inactive" "mode-line")) `.

Comment: So that is exactly as the answer currently provided. Have you looked at the answer at least? (The function does not add `nil` if you try on text that has no face-property).

Comment: Yes, but as you say, it could not be robust enough if things like `hl-line-mode` is enabled.  I would put all conditions in the body, with the interactive clause displaying only what face user wants, using simple string user selection.

Comment: I have already provided the solution for coping with `hl-line-mode` in the answer, and otherwise, my answer does exactly work as you described how you want it to in the comments. Again, in your last comment it is not clear what else you want. Please at least look at my answers before commenting again (also [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72979/pass-face-to-describe-face-when-using-function-interactively) it looks like you completely negelct my answer).

Comment: `face-at-point` can also be called like this: `(face-at-point nil t)` to return a list of faces, which might be useful if there is more than one.

Comment: @Ephram: the problem with almost all your questions is that you don't specify enough, so when somebody provides an answer to the question, you then try to fill the gaps with more questions in the comments. That is a bad model for this site: I've complained to you about that before and I will keep complaining, until you stop doing that: ask a well defined question, get a well-defined answer, accept it and move on.

Comment: I understand.  As some point out complications (e.g. have more than one face at point) I start think about that.  You are right.